# Is there any ONLINE tool with permissions management for Office 365?

Tags: permissions

I need an online tool that has option to manage user permissions for office 365, sharepoint, exchange. Does microsoft allows that type of tool without additional password request?

Comment: "without additional password request" ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

All three have a different permission models and for the moment there is no single tools which can manage all three settings at once and i believe Ms will not allow that however you can always refer the below details for a better understanding.

Office 365: In these plans, permissions for each user are defined by the management role assigned to that user. This structure is referred to as role-based access control (RBAC). 
There are eight admin roles:

Global admin,
Billing admin,
Password admin,
Service admin,
User management admin,
Exchange Online administrator,
SharePoint Online administrator,
Skype for Business Online administrator,

Exchange Online: Exchange Online also uses role-based access control (RBAC), so that permissions are determined by the user’s management role, but the admin roles used in Exchange Online are different from the roles used in the Office 365 portal.

Role-based access control in Exchange Online,
Administrator role groups in Exchange Online,
Role assignment policies in Exchange Online,
A list of all roles in Exchange Online,

SharePoint Online : SharePoint Online has its own separate security model and groups, designed specifically to secure sites, lists, and items in SharePoint Online. There is one shared role, however, and that is the SharePoint Online administrator. The person who signs up for Office 365 automatically becomes a global admin and is your SharePoint Online admin. The global admin is included as the primary site collection admin for the team site that is automatically set up for SharePoint Online.

You can find more details at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permissions-in-Office-365-da585eea-f576-4f55-a1e0-87090b6aaa9d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__what_are_the

Comment: I'm a member of every SE site, to work with [Smoke Detector](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266345/smokedetector). We are alerted to profanity, spam and a few other things from all over SE. So I suggest edits and flag appropriately for the situation. I apologise in advance if my edits are not as thorough as you'd like, as it's just a hit and run clean up job. My interests and contribution are on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on SharePoint?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/advertising).